# C++ String reaches over several NUL Bytes

Tags: c++, nul

I hate to ask this because I think this must be very trivial. But as someone who is used to high-level-languages this is a real problem.

I got a C++ program which uses PDFium to generate an Image to a PDF. And i have a C# program which communicates with the C++ program via Named Pipes. The PDF file (Which is saved as a byte-array) gets transmitted by the pipe. And here is my Problem.

On the 374th Position of the stream is a NUL byte (00) and im too stupid to somehow reach the data after it.

Here is my Code:

```
LPTSTR lpszPipename2 = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\myNamedPipe2"); 
hPipe2=CreateFile(lpszPipename2, GENERIC_READ, 0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,NULL);
if(ReadFile( hPipe2, chBuf, dwBytesToRead, &cbRead, NULL))
{
    PDFData = chBuf;
}
```

dwBytes to read is the size of the file and cbRead shows the correct number. But PDFData only contains the first 373 bytes. I checked that the data beyond the 373th position is there with the Immediate Window i just don't know how to process it.
I gotta put the Data into a char-array.

As I already said, i think this is very trivial. But although i know where the problem comes from, i have simply no idea how to fix it.

Many Thanks and Regards

Michael

Edit: The C#-Code. Its everything but perfect. But i'm very sure this Problem is on the C++ side.

```
public void SendRawData(byte[] data)
{
  while (clientse == null || clientse.stream == null)
  { }
  if (clientse.stream.CanWrite)
  {
    clientse.stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    clientse.stream.Flush();
  }
}
private void ListenForClients()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            clientHandle = CreateNamedPipe(this.pipeName, DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0, 255, BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            //could not create named pipe
            if (clientHandle.IsInvalid)
                return;

            int success = ConnectNamedPipe(clientHandle, IntPtr.Zero);

            //could not connect client
            if (success == 0)
                return;

            clientse = new Client();
            clientse.handle = clientHandle;
            clientse.stream = new FileStream(clientse.handle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, BUFFER_SIZE, true);

            if (ClientType == 0)
            {
                Thread readThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Read));
                readThread.Start();
            }                
        }
    }
```

**"Solution":**
Actually this never was a real problem. I just got my wires crossed. While chBuf seemed after copying it into PDFData or when i read its value is VS to only have those 373 bytes. All ~20 kilobytes were copied to that position.
I knew that, but i didn't understand how the PDFium sources should know that if the string terminates after 373 chars.

Well... the PDFium-sources know it cause i have to pass the length. Which was determined by

```
size_t len = PDFData.length();
```

and was therefore of course only 373 bytes.

Comment: You're not sending this data on the writer side of this pipe using a data length contrived from `strlen` or `lstrlen`, right ? What you just described at-least-sounded like you're sending a blob of goo that can contain embedded `0x00` bytes. Any usage of C string apis on *either* side of the pipe will be an effort in futility. Frankly, there is nowhere near enough data present in this question to answer it with a high degree of accuracy.

Comment: If i understand you correctly you are right. The writer side is a C# program which atm only does read a file via the framework standard method and gets the lenght by calling PDFData.Lenght

The lenght is then transmitted by the starting arguments

Comment: @Michael add the C# code to the *question* please.

Comment: I'll, give me one moment

Comment: Now that I read your post a few more times. You said `cbRead` is accurate to the number of bytes in the PDF generated on the C# side. If that is the case, you simply need to stop using string-apis from the standard library and foist your data around using a more octet-oriented (as opposed to `char`) container. A length-preamble may be warranted as well on the sender side to prepare the receiver for what is about to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this never was a real problem. I just got my wires crossed. While chBuf seemed after copying it into PDFData or when i read its value is VS to only have those 373 bytes. All ~20 kilobytes were copied to that position. I knew that, but i didn't understand how the PDFium sources should know that if the string terminates after 373 chars.

Well... the PDFium-sources know it cause i have to pass the length. Which was determined by

size_t len = PDFData.length();

and was therefore of course only 373 bytes.

I'm sorry that i bothered you with that stuff

Answer (score 1):

The null character `'\0'` is used by C/C++ to terminate `char*` strings.  So any library function (i.e. `strlen()`, `strncpy()`, *etc*) will use the null character as an implicit end-of-string indicator.  Your code is obviously doing this somewhere.  Instead, use something more like `memcpy()` or a `std::vector<char>` with an explicit data length.

Comment: +1 I'd use `std::vector<uint8_t>`, as it is just octets and not necessarily `char` data, but the idea is none-the-less accurate and worth of the up-tick.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `string:assign` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/)

String assignment operator from `char *` uses the C-style end-of-string convention. You need the "buffer" `assign` call:

```
string& assign (const char* s, size_t n);
```

This will include any `NUL`s.

That being said, vector of bytes may indeed be a better choice.